# BrowserSync with analytics scripts causing errors

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, browser-sync, brunch

We have Google Analytics and Azure Application Insights analytics scripts in our HTML, including Google Analytics. They are in `<script>` tags in `<head>`. They are causing an error when we are watching with Browsersync, particularly with browser-sync-brunch, since we are using brunch as our build system. Upon watching, however, this error is printed to the console twice (interestingly we have two analytics tags):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1494358571902-4&sid=rhGMlOFa_MbRrYbLAAAD. Request header field x-ms-request-id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

and this error set repeatedly every few seconds:

> OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1494358572782-5 400 (Bad Request)
>
> OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1494358572782-5 400 (Bad Request)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1494358572782-5. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

I'm fairly certain these analytics scripts are causing the problem because blocking them with uBlock Origin makes it work just fine.

I wondered if it had to do with these script tags being before where the Browsersync tag was injected (immediately inside `<body>` tag, see [documentation](https://browsersync.io/docs#requirements)). But moving them to the end of the `<body>` tag did not fix the issue.

What is causing this and how can it be mitigated?

Comment: does this occur on a live server, the 'localhost' makes this look like you are running this on some type of oddly configured test environment. Some remote stuff may expect to be run from the domain that it is linked to. Since you have exactly zero control over all these messy third party js things, the real question is if set of errors actually impacts functionality on the page, or is it just an error scrolling by. Our site uses some 3rd party stuff and they tend to spew out various errors but I ignore them, since I can't fix their bad code.

Comment: "some analytics scripts in our HTML" - I would actually downvote this question because you are saying you are running some unknown stuff, plus analytics, then you ask what is causing it. You have to provide all the data, all the tools you are using, it's possible someone has seen these errors attached to a specific analytic tool, but I always try to avoid running multiple analtyics 3rd party js libraries because they are all very invasive and cannot be expected to play well with others. The localhost thing is also highly suspect, it makes me think it's because the tool is linked to a domain.

Comment: @Lizardx I am running a local server as I'm developing code. I have updated it with the fact that we are using Google Analytics and Azure Application Insights.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: this is not an 'answer' but is too long to be a comment.

Using both Firefox web developer toolbar's javascript console debugger, and Chrome's, I checked our pages, which use google analytics, I believe you can largely exclude the google analytics from the suspect list, they usually do an ok job with their js.

Your errors also all point clearly to browser-sync, so that's probably the culprit. Your local dev site however is suspect, why didn't you make a proper virtual host for it, and not use localhost? I don't know anything about browser-sync so I'll just note this to exclude possibilities in your case.

I doubt your live site is running as localhost, so you might want to correct that issue to remove a possible point where small differences can creep in. I always try to use as close to live production on everything on any site I do, which would mean you'd never see a localhost anywhere in the actual running code of the site, you'd see the site either dev or real domain name, like: http://our-dev-site/ or whatever.